# Heroku as a private git repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I am new to Heroku, as I understand heroku uses git to deploy our applications. i.e. I can push my changes to the heroku repository for deployment.

Can i use heroku as a test environment and private git repository at the same time? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can push branches that are not `master` (which will not be deployed then). It might be a little slow at times.

Comment: Without creating any branch can we use master like that. Iam ok with development being public.